# USB connection issues

Tags: android, usb, samsung-mobile, usbserial

I am trying to run my android app in my samsung device GT-S6012. I use Windows 7 Home Basic. The driver is installed properly. As soon as I connect the mobile using USB cable, for some seconds "adb devices" shows my phone. But then I get a message USB connection error, windows is unable to detect the device and USB is malfunctioning.

I tried uninstalling/re-installing driver, but no luck. I tried Google on this topic but nothing solved my issue.. Can Anyone let me know how can I fix it

Answer (score 1):

> windows is unable to detect the device and USB is malfunctioning

Highly unlikely. Unless your USB connector in your Samsung device is broken, USB cable is dead, or USB port in your computer is not functioning. If it's not, you can enable ADB to work with your device by doing the following:

1. Install the Samsung Universal USB drivers for mobile devices (which I assume you have done already).
2. If ADB did not ACK/started. First, open a command prompt (since you use Windows) at \android-sdk\platform-tools\ directory and type `adb kill-server` to kill ADB. Then, type `adb start-server` to start ADB. Finally, type `adb devices` to see if ADB has recognised your devices.

See [here](http://www.androidauthority.com/about-android-debug-bridge-adb-21510/) for a list of ADB commands you can use with Android.