# Broken Windows-Android USB-Connection between Device and PC

Tags: android, windows, cordova

I've done a lot of research about rooting a device but I can not even come up to this point because my phone is not recognized by windows 8.1 at all.

My intention is to establish a usb-connection between an android-device(Samsung GT-I9506) and a pc in order to use it for phonegap. Some other devices properly work collaboratively with phonegap but this one seems to refuse all attempts.

Important points: 
1. The device is charged up when connected to a pc. 
2. Use-Debugging is enabled
3. All drivers are installed, furthermore it's a Samsung PC and Phone

A related topic is this one: [USB connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066178/usb-connection-issues)

But unlike the problem in the topic above my phone does not appear in the adb-list when entering:

adb devices

I plugged my phone into another pc(Windows 8.1) as well where it was not recognized either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed samsung drivers?

Comment: Yes, and I hope they are properly: http://www.usb-drivers.org/samsung-android-usb-device-driver.html

Comment: not really a programming related question. That's a question for XDA forums or http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, but as I saw other related questions, I didn't spend any time as to this question is more appropriate for http://android.stackexchange.com But thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the usb cable was the reason for broken communication between pc and phone.

Strange enough that this faulty cable was able to load the phone but unable to establish a communication channel to other devices.

And the moral of this story is a usb cable of a smarthphone might be faulty even if other electrial supplies are still intact.

Answer (score 1):

If your system installed `Android ADB Interface Driver` then only you can see your Device in `IDE`.

You can check that

1. Go to **Control Panel**
2. Go to **Device Manager**
3. And find **Android Phone** like

[image]

Comment: Do you have some reliable links for Android ADB Interface Driver ?

Comment: @Blauharley Go with `Pda-net`in Android .

Comment: @M D Thanks for your answer, the usb-connection seems to be broken even if I've installed Interface Drivers no new device is displayed in device-manager. But I think your solution might have solved the problem :)